# c printf like loading,not new line

Tags: c, printf

I want to update c print string in same line ,but not in new line
but I want to update multiple line.

For example, this is my code:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
  printf(" i = %d \r", i);
  fflush(stdout);
  Sleep(1000);
}
```

When run this code:

```
i = 0 ->  i = 1 -> i = 2 ....
```

this should be on same line

but now if I want to add multiple line to update,like:

```
i = 0       i = 1      i = 2
j = 0   ->  j = 1  ->  j = 2   .....
```

how can I do this?

Comment: what (and how) is `j` in the _expected_ output?

Comment: was also thinking about this sudden appearance J.

Comment: you need some library like ncurses; or terminal-escape-sequences, if you know what terminal type you are running on.

Comment: Whan you finish to print the first line, add '\n' char to go to the new line.

Comment: Am I getting this right? You would like to use printf statements for i and j in a single loop and have them printed above one another? Like, for i = 0, you would print `i = 0`, then `j = 0` below it, then go on to `i = 1`, print `j = 1` below and so on?